# Rearranging trigonometry system of equations

Tags: trigonometry, systems-of-equations

Given the following two equations:

$cos\alpha = X + Csin\beta$

$sin\alpha = Y + Ccos\beta$

Is there a way to express $\alpha$ and $\beta$  as functions of $X,Y,C$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: Recall that $\cos^2(\beta)+\sin^2(\beta)=1$ and that $\cos^2(\alpha)+\sin^2(\alpha)=1$. If you square each of your equations and add them, you get that $1=(X^2+Y^2+C^2)+2XC\sin(\beta)+2YC\cos(\beta)$. Now, $\cos^2(\beta)+\sin^2(\beta)=1$. You can use these two equations to solve for $\cos(\beta)$ and $\sin(\beta)$. Once you have them you can compute $\cos(\alpha)$ and $\sin(\alpha)$ too, from your two equations.